# how to extract variable's position in r?

Tags: r, variables, split

I have to split the data set. So I use this code.

```
a<-read.csv("philiphine.csv",header=TRUE)
factor_level<-a[, sapply(a, nlevels) > 32]
factor_names<-names(factor_level)
```

And, I will delete the factor variables that have more levels than 32 in my data set. So I used subset( )function.

```
dataset<-subset(a, selet=-c(??))
```

In ?? , I have to use variable's position. Is it possible using the variable's name?? Then, how to delete variables as using variable's names?
or Should I use only variable's position on subset( ) function?

Comment: Yep, that's the point of `subset` is that it can take the unquoted variable name. For indices or strings use `[`.

Comment: @alistaire how use it in my code??? aa<-a[,factor_names] <<This code extract the variables that have more levels than 32. how to extract except that variables?

Comment: I'd just do `dataset <- a[, sapply(a, nlevels) <= 32]`

Comment: @alistaire Thank you ^^ !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same using the below command

```
a[, sapply(a, function(col) length(unique(col))) <= 32]
```